Why is my request being made "undefined"?
I'm using node.js and express.js, and when I make a POST request to the backend, my request is being console.logged as "undefined"
Here is my backend (with express):
const express = require("express");
const de = require("dotenv");

const app = express();
de.config();
const port = process.env.PORT;

app.use(express.static("./frontend"));

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile();
})

app.post("/api/endpoint", (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.status(200).json({message: "success"});
        console.log(`request: ${req.body}`);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
})
    

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
})

and my html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Make Post Request</title>
    <style>
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        button {
            background-color: #4CAF50;
            color: white;
            padding: 14px 20px;
            margin: 8px 0;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Make Post Request</h1>
    <button onclick="makePostRequest()">Make Post Request</button>
    <script>
        async function makePostRequest() {
            await fetch('/api/endpoint', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    m: 'Hello from the frontend!'
                })
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

any solutions?
here is the console output:

I just started learning express so I don't know if it is supposed to be like that?

TL;DR you're missing app.use(express.json()). See https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#express.json and https://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#req.body
